# Send a mail with Corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk

In the line:

```
local mail1 = native.showPopup("mail")
```

I receive:
Runtime error: /Users/liorbruder/Documents/main.lua:18: attempt to call field 'showPopup' (a nil value).
It looks like Native UI doesn't have a "showPopup" property. What I miss here?
And how can I send email with Corona?

Comment: Reviewing the Corona blog suggests that showPopup is a recent addition to the program.  Have you cross checked your version level against the current level? http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/nativeshowpopup  , http://blog.anscamobile.com /2012/01/composing-email-and-sms-in-corona/  additionally can you confirm you are testing them on the device, as it looks as if the Windows and Mac emulators don't have the function, see reference link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

showPopup is available only from build 714.

For previous versions of Corona, you can use

```
local link = "mailto:nobody@mycompany.com?subject=Hi%20there&body=I%20just%20wanted%20to%20say%2C%20Hi!"
system.openURL(link)
```

See here for more details.
http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/systemopenurl

Comment: Thanks of the answer. How can I check what Corona build I have? I use for now only trial Corona SDK.

Comment: The trial build is the latest stable release which is 707 I think.  So it would probably not work for you.
You can check the version from HELP --> About Simulator.